# Whitelist of Heroku Static IP QuotaGuard is timing out to connection to Aurora Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, amazon-aurora, pgpool, quotaguard

I have a Node JS app hosted on Heroku. The Node JS app has a postgres 14 database that was migrated to Aurora Postgres on AWS. I am now trying to connect the Heroku app to the Aurora Postgres database. In AWS, access to the Aurora Postgres database is through a middleware tier called PgPool II. I have obtained two static IPs using the Heroku addon QuotaGuard. The two static IPs have been whitelisted as ingress rules on the PgPool II security group.

The odd thing is I am getting connection timeouts with the whitelist when accessing the Heroku app. If I open up the PgPool II security group then the connection works, but I need it to be not open and just allow the connection from the two static IPs. After installing the addon, I configured the tunnel with the DNS address of the PgPool EC2 instance and the port it is running on.

Any ideas on how to configure the tunnel would be appreciated.